# Python3 - Code stopped to work and shows name error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I have the following code that I always run on my server (Python3).

```py
import requests
import re
import json

links = json.loads(open('links.json').read())

for link in links:

        url = link.lower()

        headers = {
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
           'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        }

        r = requests.get(url)
        response = requests.get(r.url, headers=headers)
        response = response.text
        response = response.rstrip()
        try:
                linkdown = re.findall('(https?:\/\/k2s.cc/file[^\s]+(\.mp4|avi|AVI|wmv|WMV|flv|FLV|mpg|MPG|MP4))', response)[0]
        except IndexError:
                print('Linha não encontrada')
        string = ''.join(str(linkdown[0]))
        print(string)

        with open("k2s.txt", "a") as myfile:
           myfile.write(string  + "\n")
```

Few weeks ago, the code has stopped to work and begin to show this error:

```py
string = ''.join(str(linkdown[0]))
```

> NameError: name 'linkdown' is not defined

I really cannot understand what happened, since the code was not modified and always worked correctly.

Thank in advance for the help!

Comment: Chances are that re.findall('blablabla', response)[0] is failing because no matches are found. Then, instead of allowing the program to fail with error, you are explicitly catching the exception, printing, and allowing the program to resume even when no matches are found. What do you want to happen if no matches are found?

Comment: Did you write the code? The error implies that the line - `linkdown = re.findall('(https?:\/\/k2....` is not executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your error is that this line:

```py
try:
   linkdown = re.findall('(https?:\/\/k2s.cc/file[^\s]+(\.mp4|avi|AVI|wmv|WMV|flv|FLV|mpg|MPG|MP4))', response)[0]
except IndexError:
   print('Linha não encontrada')
```

Is not doing anything in case `linkdown` actually fails, and the variable `linkdown` is not created, hence the error:

> NameError: name 'linkdown' is not defined

Try to add:

```py
try:
   linkdown = re.findall('(https?:\/\/k2s.cc/file[^\s]+(\.mp4|avi|AVI|wmv|WMV|flv|FLV|mpg|MPG|MP4))', response)[0]
except IndexError:
   print('Linha não encontrada')
   continue # or linkdown = None #or do smtg here
```

Additionaly, it might be better to test for existence:

```py
linkdown = re.findall('(https?:\/\/k2s.cc/file[^\s]+(\.mp4|avi|AVI|wmv|WMV|flv|FLV|mpg|MPG|MP4))', response)

if linkdown:
   #do something here
```

Comment: Maybe put a `continue` statement in the `except` suite.

Comment: Just thought about that too @wwii. Thanks for that

Comment: Thank you @wwii, the continue statement solved the problem!